# trying to jump start my car but lights just flicker

Tags: subaru

I hadn’t driven my car in few months and when I tried staring it a few weeks back  it wouldn’t turn over. I tried jumping it and the lights on the dash would flicker but no signs of the car trying to start.

Answer (score 1):

The battery is likely dead, and WILL need to be replaced.  It may take a half hour or more with the jumper car running to get the battery to a state where the vehicle will crank.  Once an automotive battery has spent any time below 10 volts, it's shot.  The acid is now water, and no amount of charging will restore it to proper levels.

Check the battery voltage after disconnecting the jumper cables after 30 minutes.  If the voltage is anything less than 12.0 volts, the battery isn't taking a charge.

Even if you manage to get it started, I would replace the battery, or at least have it capacity and load tested.